# Tensorflow gradients do not exist for bias in custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've built an input convex neural network in Tensorflow following [this ArXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10962) that is a scalar output feed-forward model. The first hidden layer is dense and subsequent layers are custom that takes two inputs: the output from the previous layer (kernel) and the model input (passthrough). Separate weights are applied to each. This allows a positive weights regularizer to be applied to kernel weights but not the passthrough. I calculate the regularizer and add it using `self.add_loss` in the `call` method of the custom layer. I'm also using custom activation functions that are squared leaky ReLU and leaky ReLU.

When I am training this network I am able to calculate a gradient for the bias in the first dense layer but I get a warning that no gradient exists for the bias in the custom layer. When I add `@tf.function` to my activation functions the warning goes away but the gradient is 0. Furthermore, `loss.numpy()` throws an error when I use `@tf.function` and run in a local Jupyter notebook (but not in Colab).

Any ideas why the bias gradient exists for the dense but not the custom layer and how to calculate the bias gradient for all layers? A minimal working example is provided in this [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ndz5_wt01a48Sau9smanaVZbXjxrW9O9). Much appreciated!

Below is my custom layer. It's very similar to the standard dense layer.

```
class DensePartiallyConstrained(Layer):
    '''
    A custom layer inheriting from `tf.keras.layers.Layers` class.
    This class is a fully-connected layer with two inputs. This allows
    for different constraints on the weights of each input. This enables
    a passthrough of the inputs to each hidden layer to have no
    weight constraints while the input from the previous layer can have
    a positive constraint. It also allows for different initializations
    of the weight values for each input.

    Most of this code and documentation was borrowed from the
    `tf.keras.layers.Dense` documentation on Github (thanks!).
    '''
    def __init__(self,
                 units,
                 activation = None,
                 use_bias = True,
                 kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform',
                 passthrough_initializer = 'glorot_uniform',
                 bias_initializer = 'zeros',
                 kernel_constraint = None,
                 passthrough_constraint = None,
                 bias_constraint = None,
                 activity_regularizer = None,
                 regularizer_constant = 1.0,
                 **kwargs):

        if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
            kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)

        super(DensePartiallyConstrained, self).__init__(
                activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer), **kwargs)

        self.units = int(units)
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.passthrough_initializer = initializers.get(passthrough_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.passthrough_constraint = constraints.get(passthrough_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)

        # This is for add_loss in call() method
        self.regularizer_constant = regularizer_constant

        # What does this do?
        self.supports_masking = True

        self.kernel_input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2)
        self.passthrough_input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2)


    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Input shapes provided as list [kernel, passthrough]
        kernel_input_shape, passthrough_input_shape = input_shape

        # Check for proper datatype
        dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(self.dtype or K.floatx())
        if not (dtype.is_floating or dtype.is_complex):
          raise TypeError('Unable to build `DensePartiallyConstrained` layer with non-floating point '
                          'dtype %s' % (dtype,))

        # Check kernel input dimensions
        kernel_input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(kernel_input_shape)
        if tensor_shape.dimension_value(kernel_input_shape[-1]) is None:
          raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `DensePartiallyConstrained` '
                           'should be defined. Found `None`.')
        kernel_last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(kernel_input_shape[-1])
        self.kernel_input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2,
                                    axes={-1: kernel_last_dim})

        # Check passthrough input dimensions
        passthrough_input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(passthrough_input_shape)
        if tensor_shape.dimension_value(passthrough_input_shape[-1]) is None:
          raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `DensePartiallyConstrained` '
                           'should be defined. Found `None`.')
        passthrough_last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(passthrough_input_shape[-1])
        self.passthrough_input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2,
                                    axes={-1: passthrough_last_dim})

        # Add weights to kernel (between layer connections)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel',
                                      shape = [kernel_last_dim, self.units],
                                      initializer = self.kernel_initializer,
                                      constraint = self.kernel_constraint,
                                      dtype = self.dtype,
                                      trainable = True)
        # Add weight to input passthrough
        self.passthrough = self.add_weight(name = 'passthrough',
                                      shape = [passthrough_last_dim, self.units],
                                      initializer = self.passthrough_initializer,
                                      constraint = self.passthrough_constraint,
                                      dtype = self.dtype,
                                      trainable = True)
        # Add weights to bias
        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(name = 'bias',
                                        shape = [self.units,],
                                        initializer = self.bias_initializer,
                                        constraint = self.bias_constraint,
                                        dtype = self.dtype,
                                        trainable = True)
        else:
            self.bias = None

        self.built = True

        super(DensePartiallyConstrained, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, inputs):
        # Inputs provided as list [kernel, passthrough]
        kernel_input, passthrough_input = inputs

        # Calculate weights regularizer
        self.add_loss(self.regularizer_constant * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.math.maximum(tf.negative(self.kernel), 0.0))))

        # Calculate layer output
        outputs = tf.add(tf.matmul(kernel_input, self.kernel), tf.matmul(passthrough_input, self.passthrough))

        if self.use_bias:
            outputs = tf.add(outputs, self.bias)

        if self.activation is not None:
            return self.activation(outputs)
        return outputs
```

And my activation functions:

```
#@tf.function
def squared_leaky_ReLU(x, alpha = 0.2):
    return tf.square(tf.maximum(x, alpha * x))
#@tf.function
def leaky_ReLU(x, alpha = 0.2):
    return tf.maximum(x, alpha * x)
```

**Edit:**
With a tensorflow update I can now access `loss.numpy()` when using `@tf.function` with my activation functions. This returns 0 gradients for the bias in all of my custom layers.

I'm beginning to think that the lack of gradient for the bias terms in the custom layer might have something to do with my loss function:
[minimax loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrvLt.png)
where
[regularizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnVIP.png)
is regularization for the weights in the custom layer kernel only. The loss for `g(x)` is based on the gradient with respect to the inputs, so it doesn't contain any information about the bias (the bias in `f(x)` update normally). Still though, if this is the case I don't understand why the bias in the first hidden dense layer of `g(y)` is updated? The networks are identical other than `f(x)` has a positive constraint on the kernel weights.

Comment: When you run `model.summary()`, can you see your custom layers in the output?

Comment: Yes, I can see the custom layers in `model.summary()` and also when plotting with Graphviz. Furthermore, the first hidden dense layer weights are updated during training and it's is only connected through the custom layer.